# How to reshape a data frame from wide to long format in R?

Tags: r, reshape

I am new to R. I am trying to read data from Excel in the mentioned format

```
x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  Result
1   2   3   7   8   9    
4   5   6   10  11  12
```

and data.frame in R should take data in mentioned format for 1st row

```
x   y
1   7
2   8
3   9
```

then I want to use `lm()` and export the result to result column.

I want to automate this for `n` rows i.e once results of 1st column is exported to Excel then I want to import data for second row.

Please Help.

Comment: Can you format your question using the "code" icon? What have you tried? There are a number of packages for reading/writing to excel (do web search). I suggest you read up on some basic R syntax to see how to reorganize columns (unclear to me why you would want to do that for a lm call).

Comment: @meewoK have you put that title in place of my suggestion?

Comment: @Michele, yes. Any serious problems?

Comment: @meewoK yes,  the title doesn't make any sense. I never heard about particular method of data import for tables in the "form of columns", which even by itself doesn't make any sense... the formal label is: **wide** and **long** format. **But** even using them the title wouldn't make sense. The import (say `read.xls`) wouldn't give a **** about the shape of the table. Does it make sense?

Comment: @meewoK I also wonder which is the point of editing a question whose tag is not at all in your list of tags...

Comment: @Michele Not the scope of SO to attack the reviewer after asking you if there is a problem. Simply describe your issue next time in order to resolve it.

Comment: @meewoK sorry if you got me wrong, but your comment didn't seem so polite: 'Any serious problems?' I don't remember saying this to someone and then getting kisses and hugs...

Answer (score 3):

```
library(gdata)
# this spreadsheet is exactly as in your question

df.original <- read.xls("test.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1", perl="C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe")
#
#
> df.original
  x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
1  1  2  3  7  8  9
2  4  5  6 10 11 12
#
# for the above code you'll just need to change the argument 'perl' with the
# path of your installer
#
# now the example for the first row
#
library(reshape2)

df <- melt(df.original[1,])

df$variable <- substr(df$variable, 1, 1)

df <- as.data.frame(lapply(split(df, df$variable), `[[`, 2))

> df
  x y
1 1 7
2 2 8
3 3 9
```

Now, at this stage we automated the process of inport/transformation (for one line).

First question: How you want the data to look like when every line will be treated?
Second question: In result, what do you want exactly to put? residual, fitted values? what you need from `lm()`?

EDIT:

ok, @kapil tell me if the final shape of `df` is what you thought:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

df <- adply(df.original, 1, melt, .expand=F)
names(df)[1] <- "rowID"

df$variable <- substr(df$variable, 1, 1)

rows <- df$rowID[ df$variable=="x"] # with y would be the same (they are expected to have the same legnth)
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(split(df, df$variable), `[[`, c("value")))
df$rowID <- rows

df <- df[c("rowID", "x", "y")]

> df
  rowID x  y
1     1 1  7
2     1 2  8
3     1 3  9
4     2 4 10
5     2 5 11
6     2 6 12
```

regarding the coefficient you can calculate for each `rowID` (which refers to the actual row in the `xls` file) in this way:

```
model <- dlply(df, .(rowID), function(z) {print(z); lm(y ~ x, df);})

> sapply(model, `[`, "coefficients")
$`1.coefficients`
(Intercept)           x 
          6           1 

$`2.coefficients`
(Intercept)           x 
          6           1
```

so, for each group (or row in original spreadsheet) you have (as expected) two coefficients, intercept and slope, therefore I can't figure out how you want the coefficient to fit inside the `data.frame` (especially in the 'long' way it appears just above). But if you wanted the `data.frame` to stay in 'wide' mode then you can try this:

```
# obtained the object model, you can put the coeff in the df.original data.frame
#
> ldply(model, `[[`, "coefficients")
  rowID (Intercept) x
1     1           6 1
2     2           6 1

df.modified <- cbind(df.original, ldply(model, `[[`, "coefficients"))

> df.modified
  x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 rowID (Intercept) x
1  1  2  3  7  8  9     1           6 1
2  4  5  6 10 11 12     2           6 1

# of course, if you don't like it, you can remove rowID with df.modified$rowID <- NULL
```

Hope this helps, and let me know if you wanted the 'long' version of df.

Comment: I would like to print coefficients in result columns

Comment: @kapil ok cool, I'm on it. What about the appeareance of the final table? I'll try to guess what you want, wait some minutes and then check my EDIT.

Comment: @kapil is it what you were after?